# Load the page from an anchor link

Tags: html, anchor

Im trying to load a page from a specific anchor point

*EDIT*

See the existing example
[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2rNac/)

Desired effect will mean the red #block should appear only by scrolling up and the #content block to appear flush with the top of the browser.

**HTML**

```
<div id="block">
Top block
</div>

<div id="content">
Show this at the top
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#block {
    height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: I didn't got what you are trying to say here

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand exactly what you are trying to accomplish. Please explain what you want the end result to be, and what you are getting instead.

Comment: do you wish to load content upon creation/insertion of nodes in the user agent's internal representation (the 'dom tree') of a html page ? or do you want to insert loaded content at a given position in your document ?

Comment: Sorry, added a live example to help communicate my problem